# Transform query results values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a set of numeric identifiers (e.g. `100`, `101`, `102`, etc) that map to actions a user can take. I'd like to be able to transform those values into human readable strings so I can run a report and not have to include a legend key with it.

I took a preliminary stab at creating a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION action_to_str (integer) RETURNS text  as $$
    BEGIN
        IF $1 = 100 THEN
          RETURN "skip";
        ELSIF $1 = 101 THEN
            RETURN "save";
        ELSIF $1 = 102 THEN
            RETURN "buy";
        ELSIF $1 = 103 THEN
            RETURN "map";
        ELSIF $1 = 104 THEN
            RETURN "dismiss";
        ELSIF $1 = 105 THEN
            RETURN "share";
        ELSIF $1 = 106 THEN
            RETURN "dislike";
        ELSE
            RETURN "unknown";
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But then I get an error like this:

```
ERROR:  column "dismiss" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "dismiss"
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT "dismiss"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function action_to_str(integer) line 12 at RETURN
```

I understand what's going on (it's thinking that the result of the function is a column not a value) but I'm not sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are double quoting (`"`) the returned values. Use single quotes (`'`) instead. Double quotes are used for identifiers (not recommended). Single quotes for values.

The best practice is to create a table `action`

```
create table action (
    action_id int,
    action_description text
);
```

and join it in the query

```
select coalesce(a.action_description, 'unknown')
from
    some_table st
    left join
    action a using(action_id);
```

The mantra to get used to is: think relational not procedural